# URL scheme, should put ID in url or in parameter?

Tags: rest, url

Suppose you want a url for books of a user

You can do

```
   1. /book/{user_id}
   2. /user/{user_id}/books
   3. /book?user_id={user_id}
```

When to use each of the above and why?

Answer (score 0):

> When to use each of the above and why?

Path segments are a useful choice when you care about reference resolution, especially the ability to move about the identifier hierarchy using dot segments.  See [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5).

A query part with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` key value pairs is convenient when you want to give a client the capability to specify a specific resource within a common space of similar resources via a boring HTML form.

It's also acceptable to use both: to have multiple resources that serve duplicate content.

You can use the [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-content-location) field to indicate where the enclosed representation is actually coming from.  You can also use the [canonical link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596.html) to signal which resource is the "preferred" version.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the URL scheme would reflect the domain. e.g. if the domain was a library management system there would be a relationship between books and the users who have borrowed them. e.g. a URL that could return whether the user_id has borrowed a book could be:

```
/book/{book_id}/{user_id}
```

This isn't ideal as it's almost like `RPC` where you're calling a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. REST should return a representation of the current state of the object.

The query

> which books has this user borrowed?

could be represented by:

```
/user/{user_id}/books
```

The query

```
which users have borrowed this book
```

could be represented by:

```
/book/{book_id}/users
```

To translate into a domain:

A `User` can Borrow `Book`s

so the URL starts `/user`

a `Book` can be borrowed by `User`s

so the URL starts `/book`

Starting from either `/user` or `/book` you can then add more parts to each url to query the resource.

A query parameter is generally used to refine the result rather than influence the state of the resource. e.g. you could have different formats of the same representation:

```
/user/{user_id}/books?format=xml
/user/{user_id}/books?format=json
```